# List of hyperbolic geometry models

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

When I studied (as an amator) non-euclidean geometry I read that big number of models of hyperbolic geometry was created in 19th and 20th century. Where can I find any list and short description of such models? Usually three models are described: Poincaré Disk, Poincaré Half-Plane, Beltrami-Klein Disk, hyperboloid model. I'm looking for less classical models. Obviously I'm aware that no full list exists but some kind of partial summary, expository work could be interesting for me.

Comment: Stillwell: „Sources of hyperbolic geometry“ contains the original sources together with extensive explanations from the modern point of view. https://bookstore.ams.org/hmath-10/

Comment: I asked a question about hyperbolic models recently and was pointed to this wonderful reference: http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/cannon.pdf

Comment: W. Thurston, Three-dimensional geometry and topology.

Comment: [Whale geometry](https://static01.nyt.com/images/blogs/wordplay/Universe_in_Zero_Words_Copyright.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created this a few days ago: [Models of hyperbolic geometry](http://roguetemple.com/z/hyper/models.php)

Includes all interesting representations of hyperbolic geometry known to me :) Please tell me if anything is missing.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be good starting point for me. Are you going to add some references describing more details of all models? Obviously Google search partially solve this problem.

Comment: There have been some references at the bottom. I have added some extra ones. Also I have added links to play with the 3D models online. Thanks!